# disable form autofill in chrome in my asp.net web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, autofill

I am not sure how to disable a form autofill in chrome for my asp.net web form.

I tried a lot of code like `autocompelet="off"`,`autocompelet="disable"` `autocompelet="none"` and so on example but I didn't find a correct answer. I also tried using js, but it's not working correctly.

Comment: If "autofill chrome" means what I think it does in this context, it sounds like you're trying to control a feature of the browser that should be under user control (so a browser extension with user permissions would be the only way to make this change, if it can be made it at all.)

Comment: I havent tried anything recently, but following link discussed few solution https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8